# How to download URL from CreateObjectURL and save it in a folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a website that can record audio for 5 seconds, it works, but when the 5 seconds finish I want the audio to download or to be save in a folder of my project, is it posible? here is my code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();


    const audioChunks = [];

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);

    });

    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks)
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
      audio.play();
    });
```

And I want to make something like this

```
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks)
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
      audio.play();
      audio.save("direction-of-the-folder/") // MAKE this
    });
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: you can't save a file in a specific directory, via javascript/code, in the browser. that'd be a huge security risk

Comment: but is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, see [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).

Answer (score 0):

The [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) can provide access to the local file system ([see tutorial](https://web.dev/file-system-access/)). The recorded `audioChunks` can be also be downloaded via:

```js
function download(audioChunks) {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(audioChunks))
  a.download = 'my-audio.webm'
  a.click()
}
```

Comment: didn't you forget to remove that a tag after downloading file?

Comment: @nos_dart It's not a tag added to DOM. The `a` instance is automatically garbage-collected.